# frame 2 inside frame 1

Tags: java, swing, jframe, cardlayout

I have 2 classes; Students and RegisterStudents, and hence 2 different main_panel(Class 1) and panel_1 (Class 2). What I am trying to do is, when a button on the Students Interface is pressed, the whole panel_1 should appear within main_panel. I have set both to same size already. is that possible?

The code i got so far is:

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Register Student");
btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {


Students main_panel = new Students();
RegisterStudent panel_1 = new RegisterStudent();
main_panel.add(panel_1);


}
});
btnNewButton.setBounds(0, 162, 167, 37);
panel.add(btnNewButton);
```

This isnt doing anything though? its compiling, but panel_1 is not actually appearing inside the main_panel. Has anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: @Tim, have you got any suggestions?

Comment: Nope, just retagging so you'll get more attention.  After clicking the button, does resizing the whole window do anything?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I just tried it out. Any other ideas? been trying to figure this out for days now

Comment: Are you certain the mouseClicked is being called?  Try throwing a `System.out.println("hi");` in there to be sure.

Comment: Yes, the mouse clicked is working, cos i tried it normally by calling the frame and opening it in a separate window, and it works. i just can't get the panel_1 to be display within the same window

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson could you please suggest anything to debug this issue?

Comment: I already did.  Which part of 'SSCCE' are you having trouble understanding?

Answer (score 1):

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Register Student");
btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
   @Override
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {


       Students main_panel = new Students();
       RegisterStudent panel_1 = new RegisterStudent();
       main_panel.add(panel_1);
       panel.add(main_panel); // ADD THIS LINE
   }
});
btnNewButton.setBounds(0, 162, 167, 37);
panel.add(btnNewButton);
```

You were initializing the new `main_panel`, and new `panel_1`, and adding `panel_1` to `main_panel` but then you weren't doing anything with the new `main_panel`.

Also, I **highly** suggest naming your variables otherwise - these names are very non-intuitive.

Comment: Oh ok, i shall do so in future. But Tim, its still showing error. I tried that. Basically its underlining panel and add. When i hover over panel it says "cannot refer to a non final variable panel inside an inner class defined in a different method" and for the add it shows "the method add (Component) in the type container is nt applicable for the arguments (Students)"

Comment: It'd be helpful if you clarified how `Students` and `RegisterStudent` are defined, in addition to **where** the code you've posted is from.

Comment: I have got the code from above inside the Students class.
Basically the Students class has two panels, one left sidebar along with all the buttons, and one right panel which is the main_panel. The RegisterStudent class is one other class, which is one form with lots of labels and fields to register a new student. When someone clicks on the register button from the student class in the sidebar, then the RegisterStudent panel_1 should appear inside main_panel in Students.

Comment: No, just add to your original question what Students and RegisterStudent are.  Are they `JPanels`?  Because the error you're showing makes it look like Students is not properly typed.

Comment: Please see your answer above your comment. But yeh, I used Jpanels as kind of containers to put stuff in there.

Comment: I just checked, and i dont think, we have to do panel.add(main_panel);
because panel is only a tiny panel, that i have used in the sidebar to put all the menu buttons in. the main frame is called getContentPane() i think (according to the design view in windowbuilder)

Answer (score 1):

For such things I would suggest you to use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)
When you add something to the container, you must call revalidate() and repaint() methods to realize the changes made to it at RunTime. Like in your case you adding `main_panel.add(panel_1);`now after this you must perform

```
main_panel.revalidate();
main_panel.repaint();
frame.getRootPane().revalidate(); // for Upto JDK 1.6.
frame.revalidate();  // for JDK 1.7+
frame.repaint();
```

so that changes can be seen. A small code snippet to help you understand what I mean.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MultiplePanels extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel registrationPanel, loginPanel, searchPanel;

    private JButton registerButton, loginButton, searchButton;  

    private ActionListener action;

    public MultiplePanels()
    {       
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);            

        registrationPanel = new JPanel();
        registrationPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        loginPanel = new JPanel();
        loginPanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        searchPanel = new JPanel();
        searchPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        registerButton = new JButton("REGISTER");       
        loginButton = new JButton("LOGIN");     
        searchButton = new JButton("SEARCH");

        buttonPanel.add(registerButton);
        buttonPanel.add(loginButton);
        buttonPanel.add(searchButton);

        action = new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                JButton button = (JButton) ae.getSource();

                if (button == registerButton)
                {
                    if (!(loginPanel.isShowing()) && !(searchPanel.isShowing()))
                    {
                        add(registrationPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        if (loginPanel.isShowing())
                        {
                            remove(loginPanel);
                            add(registrationPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                        }
                        else if (searchPanel.isShowing())
                        {
                            remove(searchPanel);
                            add(registrationPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (button == loginButton)
                {
                    if (!(registrationPanel.isShowing()) && !(searchPanel.isShowing()))
                    {
                        add(loginPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        if (registrationPanel.isShowing())
                        {
                            remove(registrationPanel);
                            add(loginPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                        }
                        else if (searchPanel.isShowing())
                        {
                            remove(searchPanel);
                            add(loginPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (button == searchButton)
                {
                    if (!(loginPanel.isShowing()) && !(registrationPanel.isShowing()))
                    {
                        add(searchPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        if (loginPanel.isShowing())
                        {
                            remove(loginPanel);
                            add(searchPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                        }
                        else if (registrationPanel.isShowing())
                        {
                            remove(registrationPanel);
                            add(searchPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                        }
                    }
                }
                // This is what we are doing here to realize the changes
                // made to the GUI.
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }
        };

        registerButton.addActionListener(action);
        loginButton.addActionListener(action);
        searchButton.addActionListener(action);

        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        setSize(300, 300);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new MultiplePanels();
            }
        });
    }
}
```