# Java Swing - Multiple control sets in one window

Tags: java, swing, window

Is it possible to create something like a loading phase (contains progressbar and label etc.) then after loading is done switch to next phase with different controls like button etc. without creating a new Window for each of the phases?
I know I could probably do this using panels and changing their visibility but if they all overlaped it would be really hard to add or edit the controls.
I want to create a game and it would be really annoying if a new window opened almost everytime user did something. (example Main menu -> Shop -> Back to main menu etc.)

Comment: Please have a look at [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) :-) One small [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12284563/1057230) and another [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17876938/1057230) and another [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9425769/1057230)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this: Static and dynamic

The static way is easier, and you can accomplish it using a CardLayout. The dynamic way would require you to create methods for each screen change, which would clear all previous content and insert the appropriate controls.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html

Comment: Thanks, the CardLayout is exactly what I was looking for.